# javascript string internal representation

Tags: javascript, java, string, encoding, character-encoding

As far as I know java uses UTF-16 to represent chars and string internally,
so if we load a text file from a file it is automatically decoded to its   original encoding to utf-16.

Now the same can be said also for javascript
it also uses utf-16 as the internal string representation.
Suppose we load a string **x** encoded in utf-8 using ajax,
a converion takes place in order for javascript to be able to represent internally that string in UTF-16.

Please tell me if any of what I stated is correct or not,
because the real question is yet to come...

Now suppose the browser is rendering a page using utf-8 encoding,
and using javascript we want the browser to render also the ajax string **x** (as you normally do)
Would, in this case, a further conversion be needed from utf-16 to utf-8 ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The internal *browser* representation of strings is not specified. Browsers can be told to interpret HTML source in a variety of encodings, but once they've parsed the HTML it sort-of doesn't matter anymore. Are you having some particular problem with encodings?

Comment: your commment doesn't make much sense to me, I think it matters especially if your are using AJAX.

Comment: There's a difference between what the browser will *accept* and what it uses internally. Again, what exactly are you trying to do? Is something not working?

Comment: It's working fine, it is just a doubt on how js works with string encoding

Comment: The internal representation of Strings is not specified in Java (neither in the language, nor in the VM specification). The API of the String class makes it in most cases reasonable to choose UTF-16 as the internal representation, but it is not mandated anywhere.

Comment: @GionJh It is not clear what you are asking about. If you add content or text to a page using Javascript, it is irrelevant which character encoding was used to encode the original page.

Comment: I think java does uses UTF-16 as its internal representation of string, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

According to this [article](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding), it is USC-2 or UTF-16